# Original error: Could not initialize ideviceinstaller;

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, appium

I worked out an "Hello iOS" app by Xcode and can test it by Appium on iOS Simulator. However, I got the following error message when I tried to test the same app on a real iPhone/iPad device.

### A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not initialize ideviceinstaller; make sure it is installed and works on your system) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Here are my environment.

### xcode: 7.0.1

### mac os: version 10.11

### appium version: 1.4.13

I tried this command "brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller" but got another error message.

### configure: error: in `/private/tmp/xz20151012-43217-o3pk5w/xz-5.2.1':

### configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.

Any solution for it? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please launch "brew doctor" and share the results?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved by running these commands:

```
cd /usr/local/Library
brew update
brew install ideviceinstaller
```

Comment: I try these commands but: fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/.git/index.lock': Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled `Enable UI Automation` in device Developer settings panel?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled it. I ran this command too, "brew install ideviceinstaller" and got error message "checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/private/tmp/libtasn120151013-52895-1kpms4c/libtasn1-4.5':

configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs. Warning: You are using OS X 10.11.

We do not provide support for this pre-release version.

You may encounter build failures or other breakage."

Comment: Seems that you answered your question. You are using unsupported OSX version.

Comment: OS X 10.11 is a released version now. Who can confirm it is not supported by ideviceinstaller?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using this version 1.4.13

- Run in Terminal app:

---

> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" <
>   /dev/null 2> /dev/null

---

- press enter/return key. Wait for the command to finish.
  Run:
  brew install ideviceinstaller