# Appium on Mac OSX: Could Not Launch Appium Inspector

Tags: ios, macos, appium, appium-ios

I am using Appium 1.4.13. It works fine when I work with Android device. But when I work with iOS device (iphone6), when I run Inspector, I always get this dialog:

> Could Not Launch Appium Inspector
>
> Could not start a new session
>
> Be sure the Appium server is running with an application opened by using the "App Path" parameter in Appium.app (along with package and activity for Android) or by connecting with selenium client and supplying this in the desired capabilities object.

And in the log, I get this:

```
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u 741a0464716eeec6b0f139e688e7dbfa30c534 -l
```

I already tried to uninstall and reinstall Appium, and I installed ideviceinstaller with this commandline:

```
brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller
```

My brew command returned:

```
$ brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller
==> Cloning http://git.sukimashita.com/ideviceinstaller.git
Updating /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ideviceinstaller--git
==> Checking out branch master
==> ./autogen.sh
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ideviceinstaller/HEAD
==> make install
  /usr/local/Cellar/ideviceinstaller/HEAD: 7 files, 84K, built in 25 seconds
```

But still, I could not run Inspector, always the same error.

Thanks

Comment: did your `brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller` install succeed?

Comment: Check using `which ideviceinstaller` or `brew info ideviceinstaller` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090041/original-error-could-not-initialize-ideviceinstaller might help you as well.

Comment: @nullpointer: I supposed it's successful. I updated my question